# Transition animation loads activity with lag

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I have read many threads on this topic but seems like there is no final solution. I have an activity which loads fragment using Navigation component. I want to perform slide from right animation when activity or fragment starts. The major problem is that the activity is starting with  a few seconds lag, also there is no heavy task is executing which can cause such delay.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var binding : SecondActivityBinding
private val viewModel : PropertyViewModel by viewModels()


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = SecondActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.hold)
    
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_property)
    navController.navigate(R.id.nav_sub_property_purchase)      
  }

}
```

### SecondActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_property"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/property_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### property_navigation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/property_navigation"
app:startDestination="@+id/nav_sub_property_purchase">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_sub_property_purchase"
    android:name="com.rnsoft.SubjectPropertyPurchaseFragment"
    android:label="@string/subject_property"
    tools:layout="@layout/property_purchase">
</fragment>
```

### animation layouts slide_in_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    
   <translate
       android:duration="1000"
       android:fromXDelta="300%"
       android:fromYDelta="0%"
       android:toXDelta="0%"
       android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

### hold.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="0%p" android:duration="100"/>
```

The reason I am using hold animation is to avoid a black screen which pops up before the animation appears and removing it still show the lag. Kindly check what is the mistake, the only solution I have is to remove the transition animation.

Comment: If the second activity has a lot of info to display right away, this could cause lag because it lays out all the data, such as in a RecyclerView, on the main thread. One hack I’ve used is to delay applying the data to the adapter for 300ms so the transition animation can finish before the data starts getting laid out for display.

Comment: I don't have any recyclerview.

Comment: That’s just an example. Anything that uses very much main thread can cause animation lag.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK on first Look.

**First option:**
com.rnsoft.SubjectPropertyPurchaseFragment
Maybe here We have some performance issue.

**Second option:**
Have you started Toast just before start of `SecondActivity`
I have had a problem with fps when I was using Toast just before startActivity call.

**Third option:**
Maybe You have some SurfaceView/TextureView in Your View tree on previous screen.
Sometimes lags can be produced when You have SurfaceView not properly cleaned up